# Add empty array in to array using map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my array data :

```
var  service: [{
                id: '1',
                name: 'gana',
                age: '21',
                spare: 'rinch',
            }];
```

I want to add an static empty array inside of this data,

It is possible to insert the empty arry into another array using the map function?

my expected result is :

```
 var service: [{
                id: '1',
                name: 'gana',
                age: '21',
                spare: 'rinch',
                all:[]
            }];
```

Give any solution or idea for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `forEach`:

```js
var  service = [{id: '1', name: 'gana', age: '21', spare: 'rinch'}];
service.forEach(e => e.all = []);
console.log(service);
```

Comment: where is `map` used as it is mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var  service= [{
                id: '1',
                name: 'gana',
                age: '21',
                spare: 'rinch',
            }];
 console.log(service);
service.forEach(e => e.all= []);
console.log(service);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that just with index like the following:

```js
var service = [{
                id: '1',
                name: 'gana',
                age: '21',
                spare: 'rinch',
            }];
service[0].all = [];
console.log(service)
```

With `map()` as you mentioned in the question:

```js
var service = [{
                id: '1',
                name: 'gana',
                age: '21',
                spare: 'rinch',
            }];
service = service.map(function(i){
  i.all=[]; return i;
});
console.log(service);
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) without mutating the original array.

This proposal uses [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and builds a new object with the wanted new property.

```js
var service = [{ id: '1', name: 'gana', age: '21', spare: 'rinch' }],
    withAll = service.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { all: [] }));

console.log(withAll);
console.log(service);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `without mutating the original array.`  Good point!!, might be worth mentioning though that `Object.assign`, is not a deep copy..  Fine for flat objects like this though.

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore map you can do that easily

```
_.map([{
    id: '1',
    name: 'gana',
    age: '21',
    spare: 'rinch',
}], function(i) { i.all = [];
    return i; });
```

To test visit to [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) open inspect and paste the code to see the result